# Syntax highlighting is not working in VS Code with the Babel extension because of optional chaining

Tags: visual-studio-code, babeljs, jsx, syntax-highlighting, optional-chaining

As you can see in the picture, my syntax highlighting stops working just after I used an optional chaining in my JSX file.
Please let me know how can I fix the problem.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDgW1.png)

I am using Babel ES6/ES7 in my VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mgmcdermott.vscode-language-babel) extension should already support optional chaining. See [Add support for optional-chaining operator ?. #15](https://github.com/michaelgmcd/vscode-language-babel/pull/15). If it's not working for you, consider [raising an issue ticket](https://github.com/michaelgmcd/vscode-language-babel/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=bug-report.md&title=) with exact details to reproduce your setup and the problem.

The issue could also possibly be caused by other extensions or interference from other extensions. Ex. as found in https://github.com/michaelgmcd/vscode-language-babel/issues/94 and https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/101894. If you suspect such an issue, try disabling other JS/Babel extensions or do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect).